# cmdkey, mstsc and local tunnel

Tags: ssh, rdp, tunnel, plink

I have one problem, I am trying to run RDP with username and password set. I am using cmdkey for that. It works properly for normal connections but when I want to connect to tunneled session it doesn't fill username and password.... where's the problem?
example:

```
   cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/localhost:63344 /user:foo /pass:bar
   mstsc /v:127.0.0.1:63344
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone is curious. It was just stupid mistake - in cmdkey - port shouldn't be included! So simple...